# creating pthreads after a fork

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads, fork

I am writing a C program that forks once it accepts a client connection. Once this happens, I want to spawn two threads, but I cannot seem to get this working.

```
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    void *r_loop();
    void *w_loop();
    .
    .
    .

sockfd = accept(r_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &len);
if (sockfd < 0)
    printf("Error accepting\n");

if (!fork())
{
    int r_thread = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, r_loop, NULL);
    int w_thread = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, w_loop, NULL);

    pthread_join(r_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(w_thread, NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run this, the functions r_loop and w_loop don't get executed.

Comment: The functions need to be declared as `void * (void *)`.

Comment: Hint: always test the return value from API calls for errors.  Error codes are your friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem could be this: pthread_create() on success alwasy returns zero. You are passing to pthread_join() an incorrect value (that is zero instead of t1 and t2) making them to return immediately. Then the following exit() also kills the new starting threads

Comment: Are you using Linux/glibc? One frustrating thing about their implementation of pthreads is that `pthread_t` is defined as `long` (despite it actually storing a pointer), meaning that the compiler cannot catch errors like this. If `pthread_t` were defined as `struct __pthread_struct *` or similar, the compiler would have thrown a very informative error message.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass `t1` and `t2` instead of `r_thread` and `w_thread` to `pthread_join()`.